# Yii reset field value on addError

Tags: php, validation, model, yii

I'm looking to reset the field value when calling the addError function within a controller.

```
$model->addError('TABLE_NAME','Table "'.$model->TABLE_NAME.'" already used. Pick a new name.',array('value'=>$current_name));
```

Can I pass param values back to the activeForm textField from the addError function? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Reset? Just set it to an empty string after you have added the error.

```
$model->TABLE_NAME = "";
```

Comment: Reset to the prior value. If the form is updating, the prior value might not be empty.